# The method 'call' was called on null. Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart, callback

I'm building a calculator in flutter, I am trying to pass a callback onclick function with a parameter to the button widget which is in a different file but when I click any button it throws an exception that method was called on null. Also I dont know how to declare a function with a parameter in the CustomBtn class.

This is the main widget where I pass the function:

```
CustomBtn(
              btext: '8',
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              textColor: Colors.grey[50],
              onClick: buttonPressed('8'),
            ),
```

This is the button widget:

```
  class CustomBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String btext;
  final color;
  final textColor;
  final Function onClick;

  CustomBtn({
    this.btext,
    this.color,
    this.textColor,
    this.onClick,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text(
        btext,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, color: textColor),
      ),
      onPressed: () => onClick(btext),
      color: color,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 24.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function when you are passing it to the `onClick` parameter. Instead, just pass the reference to the function.

```
CustomBtn(
    btext: '8',
    color: Colors.grey[600],
    textColor: Colors.grey[50],
    onClick: buttonPressed,
),
```